During the Meiji era(,) when Shiki Masaoka lived

All rain shutters were made of wood during the Meiji era, when Shiki
Masaoka lived. [my sentence]

Shiki Masaoka was born and died in the Meiji era.
Is the comma after "era" necessary, or should it be removed?
I think the comma is necessary, but I have found a few sentences similar to my sentence in which no comma is used.
[Edit] In Japan, all rain shutters were made of wood before 1958.

Yes, I think the comma is appropriate because "when Shiki Masaoka lived" provides additional information. It isn't distinguishing "the Meiji era when S.M. lived" from some other Meiji era.

The form of the sentence makes sense (in an expository context) only if Masaoka had been mentioned earlier, but it would be usual to have mentioned when Masaoka lived when his name first came up. Tacking that fact onto the end of a sentence about wooden shutters is unusual. Maybe the opposite order? Masaoka lived during the Meiji era when all rain shutters were made of wood.

Thank you, Tim R. In Japan, all rain shutters were made of wood before 1958. If Shiki Masaoka had previously been referred to and my sentence used "he" instead of "Shiki Masaoka", would the comma be correct?

Not at all. I like it when it rains.

If you particularly want to refer to typical shutters during Masaoka's lifetime, why not say  All rain shutters were made of wood in Shiki Masaoka's time, during the later Meiji era.?

I did not know phrases like "Shiki Masaoka's time". Thank you very much, @KateBunting.


All rain shutters were made of wood during the Meiji era, when Shiki Masaoka lived.


Shiki Masaoka (October 14, 1867 to September 19, 1902)


Meiji era (October 23, 1868 to July 30, 1912)

Meiji era
Masaoka Shiki
As Shiki Masaoka's life didn't fully cover the full Meiji era, the version with the comma is incorrect.
Without the comma, the time frame of this rain shutter history would be from 1868 (aged one) to 1902.

Thank you, Seowjooheng Singapore. In Japan, all rain shutters were made of wood before 1958.

You're welcome, @Kaguyahime.  As this is true throughout the Meiji era, we should exclude the relative clause.

Thank you. If Shiki Masaoka had previously been referred to and my sentence used "he" instead of "Shiki Masaoka", would the comma be correct?

Hi, @Kaguyahime, you're welcome.
Using pronoun he doesn't make a difference; it still has antecedent Shiki Masaoka.

Many thanks, @Seowjooheng Singapore..

I don't see the logic of this answer.
